# jquery to enable or disable radio button based on value in a drop dwon list box?

Tags: jquery

how to enable radio button in jquery based on value given in a dropdown list box
based on employee id i should enable or disable radio button

```
<script>
    var preSelect = 'Asian';
    </script>

    <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_0" value="Alaskan Native" />
    Alaskan Native<br />
    <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_1" value="Asian" />
    Asian<br />
    <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_2" value="African American" />
    African Ame

    rican<br />
        <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_3" value="Caucasian" />
        Caucasian<br />
        <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_4" value="Hispanic" />
        Hispanic<br />
        <input type="radio" name

="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_5" value="Native American" />
    Native American<br />
    <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_6" value="Pacific Islander" />
    Pacific Islander<br />
    <input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_378508" id="CAT_Custom_378508_7" value="Other" />
    Other
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code in your question. Please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$("#drop-down").on('change', function() {
    if( $(this).val() == "some value" ) {
        // disable all enabled
        $('input[type="radio"]:enabled').attr('disabled', true);
        // enable some
        $('#CAT_Custom_378508_0, #CAT_Custom_378508_1').attr('disabled', false);       
    } else if( $(this).val() == "anuther value" ) {
        // disable all enabled
        $('input[type="radio"]:enabled').attr('disabled', true);
        // enable some
        $('#CAT_Custom_378508_2, #CAT_Custom_378508_3').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

if you want to disable all before selecting, add the property 'disabled': `<input type="radio" disabled />`

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D763G/2/**